# Dropdown bug, if clicked too quickly, options in dropdown remain visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble trying to work out why when clicking the dropdown arrow too quickly the options in the dropdown will remain even after it has closed.

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown-header">
    <h5 class="js-title-hook dropdown-title">
      Option 1
    </h5>
    <div class="toggle-button">
      <p>
        &darr;    
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-options">
    <ul class="dropdown-options-list">
      <li class="js-hook-dropdown-list" data-title="Option 1">Option 1</li>
      <li class="js-hook-dropdown-list" data-title="Option 2">Option 2</li>
      <li class="js-hook-dropdown-list" data-title="Option 3">Option 3</li>
      <li class="js-hook-dropdown-list" data-title="Option 4">Option 4</li>
      <li class="js-hook-dropdown-list" data-title="Option 5">Option 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-container{
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  color: 2b2b2b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

.dropdown-title{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.toggle-button{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.dropdown-options{
  /* padding-top: 30px; */
}

.dropdown-options{
  visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: height 1s, visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.dropdown-options-list{
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-options-list li{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-options-list li:hover{
  color: #D62727;
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){

  //Incase anything ever changes in the DOM
    var DOMstrings = {
      dropPointer: '.toggle-button',
      pageTitle: '.js-title-hook',
      dropOptions: '.dropdown-options',
      dropTitle: '.project-dropdown-title',
      listItems: '.js-hook-dropdown-list',
    }

    var dropPointer = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropPointer);
    var dropOptions = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropOptions);
    var dropTitle = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropTitle);
    var height = dropOptions.clientHeight;
    var width = dropOptions.clientWidth;

    //initisualise the height of drop options
    dropOptions.style.height = '0';

    // console.log(height + ' x ' + width);

    dropDown();

    function dropDown(){
      dropPointer.addEventListener('click', function(){

        //toggle for the pointer rotating
        if(dropPointer.style.transform !== "rotate(180deg)"){
          dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

          setTimeout(function(){
            dropOptions.style.height = height + 'px';
            dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '10px';
          }, 150)

          setTimeout(function(){
              dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';
              dropOptions.style.opacity = '1';
          }, 700)

          // console.log(height + ' x ' + width);

        } else {
          closeDropdown();
        }
      });
    }

    function closeDropdown() {
      dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
      dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      dropOptions.style.opacity = '0';

      setTimeout(function(){
        dropOptions.style.height = '0';
        dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '0px';
      }, 200);

      setTimeout(function(){
        dropTitle.style.marginBottom = "0px";
      }, 500)

    }

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.listItems);
    var title = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.pageTitle);

    // console.log(listProjects);

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      changeProject(elements[i]);
    }

    function changeProject(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        var target = e.currentTarget;
        // console.log(target);

        title.innerHTML = target.dataset.title;

        closeDropdown();
      })
    }

})();
```

The code was a little long so here is the JSfiddle that illustrates the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/andylyell/jkjxmLxx/

Thank you!

Comment: You do have an error in you code which could be causing it: `fiddle.jshell.net/:145 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at fiddle.jshell.net/:145`

Comment: Also, you could add a flag to prevent them double clicking like that when transition is taking place.

Comment: should probably avoid using `setTimeout` and just leave it to css

Comment: The issue is due to your `setTimeout` in function `dropDown()`.  If you click the dropdown button again within 700ms of opening it, the `dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';` line will be executed first, then the 700ms timeout will expire, doing `dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';`.  And so your `dropOptions` get left as `visible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a global var for the setTimeout function that make the content visible:

```
thistimeout = setTimeout(function(){
          dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';
          dropOptions.style.opacity = '1';
      }, 700)
```

Use `clearTimeout()` inside the `closeDropdown()` function  to stop the setTimeout function

```
function closeDropdown() {
  clearTimeout(thistimeout);
  dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

WORKING FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/VLK_STUDIO/jkjxmLxx/2/

```
(function(){

  //Incase anything ever changes in the DOM
    var DOMstrings = {
      dropPointer: '.toggle-button',
      pageTitle: '.js-title-hook',
      dropOptions: '.dropdown-options',
      dropTitle: '.project-dropdown-title',
      listItems: '.js-hook-dropdown-list',
    }

    var dropPointer = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropPointer);
    var dropOptions = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropOptions);
    var dropTitle = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.dropTitle);
    var height = dropOptions.clientHeight;
    var width = dropOptions.clientWidth;

    //initisualise the height of drop options
    dropOptions.style.height = '0';

    // console.log(height + ' x ' + width);

    dropDown();

    function dropDown(){
      dropPointer.addEventListener('click', function(){

        //toggle for the pointer rotating
        if(dropPointer.style.transform !== "rotate(180deg)"){
          dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

          setTimeout(function(){
            dropOptions.style.height = height + 'px';
            dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '10px';
          }, 150)

          thistimeout = setTimeout(function(){
              dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';
              dropOptions.style.opacity = '1';
          }, 700)

          // console.log(height + ' x ' + width);

        } else {
          closeDropdown();
        }
      });
    }

    function closeDropdown() {
      clearTimeout(thistimeout);
      dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
      dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      dropOptions.style.opacity = '0';

      setTimeout(function(){
        dropOptions.style.height = '0';
        dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '0px';
      }, 200);

      setTimeout(function(){
        dropTitle.style.marginBottom = "0px";
      }, 500)

    }

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.listItems);
    var title = document.querySelector(DOMstrings.pageTitle);

    // console.log(listProjects);

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      changeProject(elements[i]);
    }

    function changeProject(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        var target = e.currentTarget;
        // console.log(target);

        title.innerHTML = target.dataset.title;

        closeDropdown();
      })
    }

})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much - appreciate the answer!

Comment: I think this answer might have an occasional race condition as the following might happen (in order): `setTimeout` ends so callback is pushed into the message queue, `clearTimeout` is called (but nothing is cleared because `setTimeout` already ended), callback gets popped off the message queue and executed. This means that the dropdown would be left visible eventually. Am I correct?

Comment: @Bernard clearTimeout simply prevent a function set with setTimeout to be executed only if it hasn't been executed yet. So if the function is ended nothing happens, if the timer has started, it will stop it. Just what he needs to solve the problem. Check the fiddle and try to simulate a bug. A console error was just present before but it doesn't depend from my implementation.

Comment: @vlk My bad, just wrote some code to test `setTimeout` and you are right.  It seems like the function is guaranteed to not be executed after you call `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to your `setTimeout` in function `dropDown()`.

If you click the dropdown button again within 700ms of opening it, the `dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';` line will be executed first, then the 700ms timeout will expire, so `dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';` will then be executed – thus leaving the dropdown visible on the screen.

To fix it, inside each `setTimeout` handler, check if the dropdown is still hidden/shown before modifying the properties of `dragOptions`.

This is what I mean:

```
function dropDown(){
  dropPointer.addEventListener('click', function(){

    //toggle for the pointer rotating
    if(dropPointer.style.transform !== "rotate(180deg)"){
      dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";

      setTimeout(function(){
        if(dropPointer.style.transform !== "rotate(180deg)")return;
        dropOptions.style.height = height + 'px';
        dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '10px';
      }, 150)

      setTimeout(function(){
          if(dropPointer.style.transform !== "rotate(180deg)")return;
          dropOptions.style.visibility = 'visible';
          dropOptions.style.opacity = '1';
      }, 700)

      // console.log(height + ' x ' + width);

    } else {
      closeDropdown();
    }
  });
}

function closeDropdown() {
  dropPointer.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  dropOptions.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  dropOptions.style.opacity = '0';

  setTimeout(function(){
    if(dropPointer.style.transform === "rotate(180deg)")return;
    dropOptions.style.height = '0';
    dropOptions.style.marginBottom = '0px';
  }, 200);

  setTimeout(function(){
    if(dropPointer.style.transform === "rotate(180deg)")return;
    dropTitle.style.marginBottom = "0px";
  }, 500);
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkjxmLxx/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much! this was really helpful!